# Load a blob with viewer.loadModel()?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, gltf

I'm working on a larger project where I want to use the viewer.loadModel() function to load a GLTF.
The catch is, that I am working with a separate company. I get the GLTF from their API as a zip-file that holds the gltf and the binary file. My client is written in typescript (with React).
Right now I'm trying to load the gltf like this:

`const gltfBytes = Uint8Array.from(window.atob(response), (c) => c.charCodeAt(0)); const zip = new JSZip(); await zip.loadAsync(gltfBytes); const files = zip.files; const gltf = await files["scene.gltf"].async("uint8array"); const bin = await files["scene.bin"].async("uint8array"); const gltfBlob = new Blob([gltf], {type: "model/gltf+json"}); const binBlob = new Blob([bin], {type: "application/octet-stream"}); const gltfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(gltfBlob); //const binUrl = URL.createObjectURL(binBlob); viewer.loadModel(gltfUrl.substring("blob:".length) + ".gltf", null);`

I have tried different things for the viewer.loadModel parameters but I don't seem to get it right.
The url looks like this "http://localhost:3000/05bff201-dd63-47fb-800d-3860dd3c676b.gltf" and when I use this as a parameter, the viewer starts loading for a while before it quits saying there are "Network problems".

Question is: Am I doing it wrong on the client-side or is the whole approach not really correct by sending the gltf and its binary through an API?

So far I have tried to call the function like this:

`viewer.loadModel(gltfUrl + ".gltf", null); viewer.loadModel(gltfUrl.substring("blob:".length) + ".gltf", null); viewer.loadModel(gltfUrl.substring("blob:".length), {binary: binUrl.substring("blob:".length)}, null);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work. The .gltf file references the .bin file internally, and if you convert both of these files to blob URLs, the viewer won't be able to resolve the reference.

Instead, if you could ask your client's API for a single .glb file, such blob *can* be loaded into the viewer. You'll just need to hint to the viewer that the blob URL should be loaded with a glTF/glb loader:

```js
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'Local' }, async function () {
    const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(/* ... */);
    viewer.start();
    await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.glTF');
    const resp = await fetch('/path/to/your.glb');
    const blob = await resp.blob();
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    viewer.loadModel(url, { fileLoader: Autodesk.Viewing.FileLoaderManager.getFileLoaderForExtension('glb') });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Petr. I've been distracted by other projects recently. I have tried your code but FileLoaderManager does not seem to exist on Autodesk.Viewing. There is only FileLoader which makes it a little bit more complicated. Im getting my types from this package: "@types/forge-viewer": "^7.69.5"

Comment: Hi! Please note that the TypeScript definitions in `@types/forge-viewer` may be incomplete.